# Unable to connect Win7 Ultimate to Win7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a Win7 32 bit PC I am using as a file server with a couple of external drives hanging off of it. I have a 64bit Win7 Pro desktop and a 32bit Win7 Pro laptop that can map to the "file server" with no problem.

I also have another 64bit Win 7 box running Ultimate that, using the exact same settings, cannot map to it.

I can Remote Desktop to the server from the desktop and successfully ping it, but I cannot map to it.

I keep getting "\[serverName] is not accessible. Might not have permission to use this network resource. The specified network provider name is invalid". What am I missing?

Please don't tell me it is an issue between Pro and Ultimate or 32 vs. 64 bit. That would really drive me crazy.

Comment: Its not an issue between Pro and Ultimate, the only explation of your problems, is the configureation is wrong.

Comment: Where would you suggest I look? As I said, all 3 machines are configured the same and are connected to the same router to boot. There appears to be no difference anywhere, just that one machine doesn't want to connect.

Answer (score -1):

It should work fine. Check some of the following things:

- Are both systems set into the same workgroup? You can check this by right-clicking on  computer, select propeties and scroll down a bit.
- Check that you use the same user credentials at both computers.

Comment: All are in WORKGROUP and I am using the same credentials on all 4 machines.

Comment: Allright, so that couldn't be it. Try browsing to the server directely using explorer. [This](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/the-specified-network-provider-name-is-invalid/5957318d-3dc3-46c3-99ec-f0b67a1f520b) might also work. It can't be a problem between Windows 7 Ultimate and Pro,  because I use that set-up for over two years now and it works fine.

Comment: When you say to browse the server using explorer, do you mean from the Ultimate box? That is when I get the error I mentioned. I can Remote Desktop to it and ping it, I just cannot access it thorough Explorer or map to it

Comment: One more thing, the server shows up under Network in Explorer so it knows it is there.

Comment: What location are you attempting to navigate to? Is do you have the admin share enabled (`\\(PC)\c$`)?

Comment: No I mean, double click on the server in Windows Explorer. Can you browse to it using that way? because if you can you probably misspelled the path when you was mapping it.

Comment: Jelle, no I cannot access it by double clicking on it in Explorer - the error I posted above happens. 

Qwilson, admin share would have to be enabled otherwise the other two machines wouldn't be able to get to it. It is just this one machine that is having problems, the two work fine.

Comment: I ended up having to completely reinstall Windows 7 Ultimate in order to make it work. Something must have gotten messed up during the  original install. Once I did the new install, it immediately saw the network and all the machines on it. Thank you to everyone for your suggestions.